# How to convert saz file to pcap

Tags: fiddler, wireshark

I have some `*.saz` files which I need to have them as `pcap` files.

Is there any such way in `Fiddler` or `Wireshark` to make it happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to http://fiddler.wikidot.com/saz-files, `*.saz` files don't actually contain the full network packets which would be necessary to convert them into PCAPs, they only contain the HTTP-level information.

Comment: That's correct. While you can write a SAZ->PCAP converter (and someone out there has done so) there's really no good reason to do so. If you want PCAPs, capture them directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fiddler2pcap python script to convert saz->pcap](https://github.com/EmergingThreats/fiddler2pcap)

**fiddler output to pcap**

Example saz file as input:

`./fiddler2pcap.py -i /home/blah/Downloads/Infinity_2014-03-17.saz -o infinity.pcap --saz`

Example raw directory as input:

`./fiddler2pcap.py -i /tmp/tmpaPRU3T/raw/ -o infinity.pcap`

**Help Usage:** `fiddler2pcap.py [options]`

```
Options: 
-h, --help show this help message and exit 
-i INPUT_TARGET path to fiddler raw directory we will read from glob format or path to saz file with --saz option 
-o OUTPUT_PCAP path to output PCAP file 
--src=SRCIP src ip address to use if not specified we read it from the XML 
--dst=DSTIP dst ip address to use if not specified we read it from the XML 
--dproxy attempt to unproxify the pcap 
--saz input is saz instead of raw directory None
```